# How can I change path for packages folder for MsBuildTasks in module FormAndList (aka UserDefinedTable)?

Tags: c#, msbuild, dotnetnuke

I'm trying to make DNN module FormAndList (aka UserDefinedTable) to compile while I included it's project into solution, which is placed in different directory (3 folders up). And I edited `MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets` file so that it would find correct path to library `MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll`. And it works for Debug mode, but when I compile it in Release mode it gives me this error:

`The "MSBuild.Community.Tasks.XmlRead" task could not be loaded from the assembly D:\Projects\SolutionFolder\Host\DesktopModules\UserDefinedTable\BuildScripts\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'file:///D:\Projects\SolutionFolder\Host\DesktopModules\UserDefinedTable\BuildScripts\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.`

I compared both `MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets` and `ModulePackage.targets` files with another module, which works perfectly, but I didn't find any crutial difference between them.

Problem is that during compilation it tries to find `MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll` iside folder where build scripts are, but it should search for it in `D:\Projects\SolutionFolder\packages\MSBuildTasks.1.5.0.235\tools`.
I already edited all places that I found with path's in .csproj and `MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets` but it works only for Debug mode. What am I missing?

Comment: Could you post your csproj file? Also packages.config

Comment: Update. Here is link to github with code. https://github.com/NetLS2013/DNN_FormAndList_modified. In attempts to make module get package from sln directory I modified .csproj, MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets and packages.config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your projects you have something like:

```
<Import Project="..\..\..\packages\MSBuildTasks.1.5.0.235\build\MSBuildTasks.targets" Condition="Exists('..\..\..\packages\MSBuildTasks.1.5.0.235\build\MSBuildTasks.targets')" />
```

and

```
<Import Project="packages\MSBuildTasks.1.5.0.235\build\MSBuildTasks.targets" Condition="Exists('packages\MSBuildTasks.1.5.0.235\build\MSBuildTasks.targets')" />
```

I don't think you need those lines.

also try to use:

```
<MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>$(SolutionDir)\packages\MSBuildTasks.1.5.0.235\tools</MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>
```

[image]

Comment: I tried already to use `$(SolutionDir)` instead of `..\..\..`, but it didn't help. It just works the same way, but it doesn't help. And I edited those paths both in .csproj and build script for MsBuildTasks. At first I had problem, that at build time this project couldn't find package `MSBuildTasks.1.5.0.235`. With `$(SolutionDir)` or `..\..\..` in path it finds it, but then appears error above with the `MSBuild.Community.Tasks.XmlRead` task.

Comment: I've just received permission from my company to public code for whole module and folder packages, so I added link to another github repo in comment above.

Comment: @ConstantineKetskalo check https://github.com/ericklanford/DNN_FormAndList_modified

Comment: Wow. Thanks, @ErickLangfordXenes. Unfortunately it didn't build right away. Probably because we deploy different versions of DNN website and with different settings. Anyway, I just checked difference between files .csproj, packages.config and files in folder BuildScripts in both current project FormAndList and newer working Module, created by me. Edited differences according to newer project and it worked. You helped me to come up with the idea. Thanks. )